# How to put all my files name in one file?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to merge all my numpy files in one numpy file,then convert that file in a binary file. I try firstly to create two different  list files where I merge the files're name in two different lists. 
My folder which contains the numpy file looks like this:

```
File1_Trace1
File2_Trace2
File2_Trace3
```

I try to use this code:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import os

# be sure to pass numbers on command line
if len(sys.argv)==3:
    start_index, stop_index = int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2])
else:
# or just use
    start_index, stop_index = 1, 1000

path = r'Y:\My_Scripts'
File_path= r'Y:\My_Scripts\1000_Traces'
lines_npy = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(os.path.join(path, 'Traces.list_npy'))]
lines_bin = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(os.path.join(path, 'Traces.list_bin'))]
all_traces = np.zeros((stop_index - start_index + 1, 8000))
for x in range(start_index, stop_index):
    trace = np.load(os.path.join(path, lines_npy[x]))
    trace.astype('float32').tofile(os.path.join(File_path, lines_bin[x]))
    all_traces[x] = trace
    all_traces.astype('float32').tofile(os.path.join(path, 'TRACES.bin'))
```

The problem that it doesn't work, At first it ask me for the two lists file. then it dipslay me this error:

```
  trace = np.load(os.path.join(path, lines_npy[x]))
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: are you sure lines_npy and lines_bin are initialized correctly. I really doubt those lines.

Comment: The problem is that I try to create them directly, but I can't

Comment: `IndexError: list index out of range`, you know why this occurs ? check start_index, stop_index

Comment: @saikumarm, as I understand the problem is with  the creation of the both lists, for that they don't find the correct the start_index, stop_index. But I am blocked I don't know how to make it works correctly

Comment: you could use `for x in range(min(len(lines_npy, lines_bin))`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with indexing `lines_npy`; `x` is an invalid value, probably too large.  To track that down you need to focus on this part of the code:

```
# be sure to pass numbers on command line
if len(sys.argv)==3:
    start_index, stop_index = int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2])
else:
# or just use
    start_index, stop_index = 1, 1000

path = r'Y:\My_Scripts'
File_path= r'Y:\My_Scripts\1000_Traces'
lines_npy = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(os.path.join(path, 'Traces.list_npy'))]

print(len(lines_npy)
print(start_index, stop_index)

for x in range(start_index, stop_index):
    print(lines_npy[x]))
```

The default `stop_index` indicates that you could have 1000 files?  Does that make sense?

Comment: thank you for your answer, Results that I found are lines_npy= [] is empty,  start_index=1, stop_index=1000, so the problem is how to put the name of all my files in one list.

Comment: `glob` is a nice tool for fetching names of files in a directory.